# using asio in a ros2 package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a sanity check on this idea from more experienced developers.

ros2 is installed on an Nnvidia TX1 using a docker container of the ros galactic release.  The container runs a c++ ros2 package with the asio library working as a socket server, listening on port 9090 for example.

Messages come in on port 9090 from the web browser of an Android device; or any web browser really.  Messages sent to 9090 from the browser are in JSON format and contain linear and angular velocity.  The code bound to the socket then creates a Twist message with these values and publishes them on cmd_vel.

There is also a micro-ros agent running on the TX1 that forwards the cmd_vel to a micro-ros instance running on an ESP32 board that is connected to the motor driver.

I am basically trying to create a simple remote control interface from the android phone without having to bother with ros2-java or building an Android app.

I already turned the TX1 WiFi interface into an access point and connected to it from the phone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388619/using-asio-in-a-ros2-package/) by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2021-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say that's pretty rational. Depending on your needs on the microcontroller, I might even suggest just removing ROS 2 from the equation completely. I wouldn't bother converting to Twist just to pass things around unless you're leveraging some other tools (like TF) that expect it to be in a particular data format to operate on.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on 2021-10-13**:
Thanks for the quick reply! I want to use ros2 for practice of TF, diff drive control loop, IMU sensor, and monocular SLAM.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-10-14**:
Makes sense then.